# Hook into collection creation to set Schemas Spring Data Mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

When your start a spring boot app with mongo repositories enabled all the collections are done. And the basic mappings are fine. Now since spring-data-mongo:2.2 there is a new warning introduced on startup:

```
Automatic index creation will be disabled by default as of Spring Data MongoDB 3.x.
Please use 'MongoMappingContext#setAutoIndexCreation(boolean)' or override 'MongoConfigurationSupport#autoIndexCreation()' to be explicit
```

So there must be a default bean somewhere that is the MongoMappingContext. How to find the default default implementation of that bean and override it?

Also I would like to set JSON schema at collection creation. The mappings are totally fine but I need a schema validation in their too. Spring offers a schema builder which is mostly sufficient so I want to add those schemas in when the collections are first created. Is there any hook to that like the lifecycle hooks? If not a direction what I have to overwrite in my own config would be nice while keeping the spring way to leave everything I don't need to change as is.